# How to faster the execution of shell_exec?

Tags: java, php

So I have a shell exec command that run a a java command, load a jar file it ask for input then produce an output in the browser. I'm done with the coding and its working just fine, but the problem is its a bit slow. So, is there a way to make it faster? A certain command or something?

Comment: Convert the java code to C

Comment: Use metrics and analysis tools to see where the bottle neck is, then replace with a more efficient algorithm.